# specification/implementation behaviour for empty href?

Tags: browser, hyperlink

I once read a page a few years ago about the various browsers' differing implementations of behaviour when a link with an empty href is clicked.

- some of them linked to the directory (`/path/to/file?query` → `/path/to/`)
- some of them linked to the exact same URI (`/path/to/file?query` → `/path/to/file?query`)
- some of them linked to the same page (`/path/to/file?query` → `/path/to/file`)

...and various other behaviours.

- Is the behaviour defined in a specification?
- If so, what is the correct behaviour?
- If so, have the latest versions of the big five browsers today fixed their implementations?

Comment: "what is the correct behaviour?"  That's funny.  It doesn't matter what's *correct*.  The only thing that matters is what browsers really do.  "latest versions of the big five browsers today fixed their implementations"?  You can download them and try them out for yourself, you know.  What's stopping you from running the experiment?

Comment: Well, for a start, testing Internet Explorer won't be easy as all my boxes run Ubuntu Server, and ies4linux/Wine isn't a highly reliable environment. As for the other four, I can test them, and I will now; thanks.

Comment: If all you're doing is testing IE, look to eBay or Craigslist.  Buy a super cheap used PC with Windows and use that for IE testing.  It looks like $150.00 gets you a working computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no "specification" for contents of HREF (at least in [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-href)), the browsers can do whatever they damn well please.

**UPDATE** However, aside from HTML, there's an [RFC3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). It has section  [4.4.  Same-Document Reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.4) which says:

> When a URI reference refers to a URI that is, aside from its fragment
> component (if any), identical to the base URI (Section 5.1), that
> reference is called a "same-document" reference.  The most frequent
> examples of same-document references are **relative references that are empty** ...

I do not necessarily read the above as "an empty URI MUST cause the client to reload the same socument's URI", but it does sound like a "best practice" type of wording; so if I was implementing my own browser I'd almost certainly follow such a behavior.

On a related note, here's a good recent 3/2010) roundup of how browsers treat empty `src` attribute of `<img>` tag: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/16/empty-string-urls-in-html-a-followup/ and http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/07/13/empty-string-urls-browser-update/ . Please note that **it is a big deal**, since having and empty img src would cause the page to endlessly re-load itself in the worst case scenario.

Comment: Then Syntax is specified (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-uri).  The behavior in 12.2.4 Unavailable and unidentifiable resources
says "If a user agent cannot locate a linked resource, it should alert the user".  So I think there **is** a specification.  It's a bit thin on details, but it does seem to exist.

Comment: @S.Lott - the W3 HTML spec links to RFC 1630 (and elsewhere, confusingly enough, to 2396 which I think superseded it). The latest URI RCF is actually 2005 RFC 3986 linked in the update to my answer.